# About distribution convergence consequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution. Are there $Y_n$ and $Y$ such that $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ almost surely and their distribution functions satisfy $F_{X_{n}}=F_{Y_{n}}$, $F_X=F_Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is called the [Skorokhod representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod's_representation_theorem). Note that, using the notation from wikipedia, separability of the support of $\mu_\infty$ is always given when the metric space $S$ is already separable - as is the case for $S=\Bbb R^N$.